# Type Mismatch with Like "*"

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I get a type mismatch where it's trying to set my `Like "*"`

I set Dim to a String and this field is all short text.

In an Access query it works.

I tried it this way (preferred)

```vb
Private Sub AppendFilter_Change()
    Dim UserF As String
    Dim DateF As String
    
    UserF = Me.UserFilterCombo
    DateF = Me.AppendFilter
    
    If UserF = "" Then
       UserF = "Like "*"" '<---Type Mismatch??
    Else
    End If
    
    Me.TasksLst.RowSource = "SELECT tblTasks.ID, tblTasks.Owner, tblTasks.[Task Name], tblTasks.Priority, tblTasks.Company, tblTasks.Status, tblTasks.Notes, tblTasks.DueDate, tblTasks.StartDate, tblTasks.DateCompleted, tblTasks.DateCreated, tblTasks.[Need Help], tblTasks.Assigned " _
    & "FROM tblTasks " _
    & "WHERE (((tblTasks.Owner)='" & UserF & "') AND " & DateF & " AND ((tblTasks.[Recurring Event])=False)) OR (((tblTasks.Owner)='" & UserF & "') AND ((tblTasks.Status)='Not Started') AND " & DateF & " AND ((tblTasks.[Recurring Event])=False)) OR (((tblTasks.Owner)='" & UserF & "') AND ((tblTasks.Status)='In Progress') AND " & DateF & " AND ((tblTasks.[Recurring Event])=False)) " _
    & "ORDER BY tblTasks.Owner, tblTasks.DueDate;"
    
    Me.TasksLst.Requery
End Sub
```

I tried it this way (not my favorite)

```vb
Private Sub AppendFilter_Change()
Dim UserF As String
Dim DateF As String

UserF = Me.UserFilterCombo.Value
DateF = Me.AppendFilter

If UserF = "" Then
Me.TasksLst.RowSource = "SELECT tblTasks.ID, tblTasks.Owner, tblTasks.[Task Name], tblTasks.Priority, tblTasks.Company, tblTasks.Status, tblTasks.Notes, tblTasks.DueDate, tblTasks.StartDate, tblTasks.DateCompleted, tblTasks.DateCreated, tblTasks.[Need Help], tblTasks.Assigned " _
& "FROM tblTasks " _
& "WHERE (((tblTasks.Owner) Like " * ") AND " & DateF & " AND ((tblTasks.[Recurring Event])=False)) OR (((tblTasks.Owner) Like " * ") AND ((tblTasks.Status)='Not Started') AND " & DateF & " AND ((tblTasks.[Recurring Event])=False)) OR (((tblTasks.Owner) Like " * ") AND ((tblTasks.Status)='In Progress') AND " & DateF & " AND ((tblTasks.[Recurring Event])=False)) " _
& "ORDER BY tblTasks.Owner, tblTasks.DueDate;"

Else
Me.TasksLst.RowSource = "SELECT tblTasks.ID, tblTasks.Owner, tblTasks.[Task Name], tblTasks.Priority, tblTasks.Company, tblTasks.Status, tblTasks.Notes, tblTasks.DueDate, tblTasks.StartDate, tblTasks.DateCompleted, tblTasks.DateCreated, tblTasks.[Need Help], tblTasks.Assigned " _
& "FROM tblTasks " _
& "WHERE (((tblTasks.Owner)='" & UserF & "') AND " & DateF & " AND ((tblTasks.[Recurring Event])=False)) OR (((tblTasks.Owner)='" & UserF & "') AND ((tblTasks.Status)='Not Started') AND " & DateF & " AND ((tblTasks.[Recurring Event])=False)) OR (((tblTasks.Owner)='" & UserF & "') AND ((tblTasks.Status)='In Progress') AND " & DateF & " AND ((tblTasks.[Recurring Event])=False)) " _
& "ORDER BY tblTasks.Owner, tblTasks.DueDate;"

End If

Me.TasksLst.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: Your quotes are wrong. `Like` is an operator like `+`.  `UserF = "MyString" Like "*"` See more examples https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator

Comment: `UserF = "Like "*""` is interpreted like multiplication of two strings. You probably wanted `UserF = "Like ""*"""` ?

Comment: I'm also not sure of your intent. But it seems you are testing if a string has zero or more characters. Every string in Basic is zero or more characters.

Comment: Also don't you need to use `LIKE '*'` with single quotes? If you are trying to make SQL query...

Comment: Thanks! I knew it had to be something I was missing. Still having an issue with my search criteria though. No more error but no results based on the Like "*" yet either. Looking into that now.

Comment: I'm using SQL through the Access query builder. So I THINK I can use double quotes?? It's never been clear. I know that there are times I can, and times a can't. Haven't figured that out yet.

Answer (score 2):

I would have your logic so that the Where clause doesn't mention the user at all if the user hasn't specified a user (and same for date range - unless you want to put a default date range).

something like the below ... I haven't passed SQL statements to the rowsource, so I don't know how it uses the LIKE statement ... in SQL it would be single quote and % sign .... based on you using the *, this code uses single quote and star.

```
Private Sub AppendFilter_Change()
    Dim UserF As String
    Dim DateF As String
    
    UserF = Me.UserFilterCombo
    DateF = Me.AppendFilter
    
    If UserF = "" Then
       UserF = ""
    Else
        UserF = " AND (tblTasks.Owner) LIKE '*" & UserF & "*'"
    End If
    'repeat for DateF
    
    Me.TasksLst.RowSource = "SELECT tblTasks.ID, tblTasks.Owner, tblTasks.[Task Name], tblTasks.Priority, tblTasks.Company, tblTasks.Status, tblTasks.Notes, tblTasks.DueDate, tblTasks.StartDate, tblTasks.DateCompleted, tblTasks.DateCreated, tblTasks.[Need Help], tblTasks.Assigned " _
    & "FROM tblTasks " _
    & "WHERE (( ((tblTasks.[Recurring Event])=False)) OR (((tblTasks.Owner)='" & UserF & "') AND ((tblTasks.Status)='Not Started') AND " & DateF & " AND ((tblTasks.[Recurring Event])=False)) OR (((tblTasks.Owner)='" & UserF & "') AND ((tblTasks.Status)='In Progress') AND " & DateF & " AND ((tblTasks.[Recurring Event])=False)) " _
    & UserF & DateF _
    & " ORDER BY tblTasks.Owner, tblTasks.DueDate;"
    
    Me.TasksLst.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh that's good. This is definitely a solution I hadn't though of :) Appreciate it!